# Upload gets to 5%, then resets to 0%

Tags: php, jquery, fine-uploader

I'm having some issues with fine-uploader. With smaller files (~20MB), everything is great. However, with larger files (100MB+), the files will upload to around 5%, then the progress bar will reset back to 0%.

Upload eventually fails with "Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)".

In my endpoint (upload.php), my very last line is "echo json_encode($result);". $result is an array, and here's the relevant PHP:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $result = array('success'=> true);
    $result['uploadName'] = $file['name'];
} else {
    $result = array('error'=> "Upload failed");
}
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Is this an issue with upload.php or is something funky happening with fine-uploader?

Comment: you may want to check your php.ini file since i believe 50MB is the limit for uploads by default. If you want to increase it you will have to alter your php.ini.

Comment: did you check `$file['error']` for non-zero values?

Comment: I've set upload limits for php to 350MB in phprc file on my dreamhost server. Didn't check $file['error'], will check it out shortly and will report back.

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of an error in your server-side code your your server environment.  Surely there is an error returned by your server.  This will be reported in the javascript console.  Please have a look.

Comment: Well thats what I thought too, but console is fairly unhelpful. I put the contents here:
[gist with console contents](https://gist.github.com/tlongren/5381192)

I'm not sure what could be happening on the server-side that would cause fine-uploader to report 5% having been uploaded, to 0% uploaded. And it'll do that 3 or 4 times before the upload finally fails.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the link to your gist.

Comment: The text "gist with console contents" was linked.
[https://gist.github.com/tlongren/5381192](https://gist.github.com/tlongren/5381192)

Nice to see you keeping such a close eye on this fine-uploader tag. :)

Comment: The javascript console error message suggests that your server is returning a response that is not valid JSON.  Most likely, your server code is doing something unexpected and the resulting error making its way into the response.  There isn't much I can do other than tell you to figure out where your server is failing to handle the request properly.  What are you seeing when you look at the response in Chrome or Firebug's network tab?

Comment: Network tab doesn't show much more, only that the request to my endpoint took 1.5 minutes. But thank you for confirming that is an issue with the server-side stuff. That at least narrows the possibilities down.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no response content when the upload fails. Response is good when the upload succeeds though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this issue was being caused by CloudFlare.

I added a custom page rule for the entire directory containing my upload stuff, but it didn't seem to help. The page rule essentially disabled all the CloudFlare stuff for that folder, and everything in it (unless I'm not understanding the functionality of page rules).

Pausing CloudFlare on the domain seemed to fix it though. Uploading large files has worked since pausing CloudFlare.

A CloudFlare employee [mentioned something here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4297037.htm).